# Como relacionar tabla Pivot y mostrar los datos

Tags: laravel

Tengo las siguientes tablas

Tabla party_names

```
    Schema::create('party_names', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('nameParties')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Tabla characters

```
    Schema::create('characters', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('Name')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('Level')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('Power')->nullable();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_party')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('id_party')->references('id')->on('parties');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_characterClass')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('id_characterClass')->references('id')->on('class_names');
        
        $table->timestamp('dateForm')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

tabla intermedia

```
    Schema::create('parties', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_nameParties')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('id_nameParties')->references('id')->on('party_names');
        $table->integer('amount')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Al crear un registro en la tabla characters y mostrarla en la vista

```
@foreach ($characters as $item)
    <div class="col-md-auto text-center">
        <p class="text-muted">
            @if ($item->Name == null)
                <div class="text-danger">
                    N/A
                </div>
            @else
                {{ $item->Name }}
            @endif
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto text-center">
        <p class="text-muted">
            @if ($item->Level == null)
                <div class="text-danger">
                    N/A
                </div>
            @else
                {{ $item->Level }}
            @endif
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto text-center">
        <p class="text-muted">
            @if ($item->characterPower == null)
                <div class="text-danger">
                    N/A
                </div>
            @else
                {{ $item->Power }}
            @endif
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto text-center">
        <p class="text-muted">
            @if (empty($item->id_party))
                <div class="text-danger">
                    N/A
                </div>
            @else
                {{ $item->id_party }}
            @endif
        </p>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar el nombre la Party en el campo {{ $item->id_party }} pero no se como hacer la relación para que acceda al nombre de la Party, intente lo siguiente pero no funciona

modelo characters

```
public function partyName()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(partyName::class, 'party')
        ->withPivot('id_party');
}
```

Asumiendo que no tengo echas mas relaciones, creería que me hace falta relaciones en los modelos de **Party_name** y en el modelo **parties** los cuales no tengo claro tampoco

Comment: intenta asi public function party(){ return $this->belongsToMany(partyName::class, 'party');} y en el foreach {{ $item->party->nameParties }}

Comment: No funciona ya que hay una tabla intermedia que  une  las dos relaciones